# How to show String instead of integer in tableview (FXML)

Tags: javafx, combobox, tableview, fxml

I Have a field in my database table which stores integers. To make program more user-friendly I want to represent data as string instead of integer in TableViews and ComboBoxes. For example instead of 0 it should show "unsupported" and instead of 1 it should show "supported". This is one of my fields:

```
private final SimpleIntegerProperty status = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper();
 public int getStatus() {
    return status.get();
}
public void setStatus(int val)
{
    status.set(val);
}
```

I retrieve and inject data to a TableView using FXML with success but it shows 0 or 1; How do I implement this in Java?

I need a solution for ComboBoxes so user can select a meaningful string instead of a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your `StringConverter` which can convert each status to expressions what you want.

```
public class StatusStringConverter extends StringConverter<Integer> {

    // Manage selectable options as Integer here
    final public static ObservableList<Integer> OPTIONS = FXCollections.observableArrayList(0, 1);

    @Override
    public String toString(Integer value) {
        switch (value) {
            case 0: return "unsupported";
            case 1: return "supported";
            default: return "-";
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Integer fromString(String string) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Using `ComboBoxTableCell` with the `StatusStringConverter` enable to show your expressions in cells and `ComboBox` choices. Try it out.

```
table.setEditable(true);
column.setEditable(true);
column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("status"));
column.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(
        new StatusStringConverter(), StatusStringConverter.OPTIONS));
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. thnx